# Should we make it clearer when someone is asking a more generic question over an specific implementation question?

Tags: discussion, edits, scope, asking-questions

For instance, I was looking for a problem that was *a more generic* one and found this question:

*[Global variable doesn't get updated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65383461/global-variable-doesnt-get-updated)*

that, in fact, was not about *a global variable problem*, but instead a very particular implementation, something like "how can I set a button that takes the next value from a fetch?" and tagged as *vanilla JS* (only [javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/javascript))

I  was tempted to use the word *theory* since I saw all these tags.

[image]

I recently found a good example of a "theory question" and I don't think it's considered non-related to Stack Overflow. For instance, these question has almost 6k upvotes:

[What is the difference between "let" and "var"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/what-is-the-difference-between-let-and-var/11444416#11444416)

Comment: Theoretically theoric questions are off-topic here... the site is about practical problems

Comment: Wait, how is the linked question theoretical?  There's real code and a JSFiddle that shows what the person is trying to accomplish.

Comment: @Makoto I understood that the OP is looking for theory... but they found real code

Comment: @Rubén: My brother in Stack Overflow, did you even read the linked question??  This doesn't look theoretical in the slightest.  There is no hand-waving, no guessing, no what ifs here.  There is real JavaScript with a real JSFiddle attached to it.

Comment: The second one, clearly. I mean it is still an implementation problem but with a clearly more generic implementation. The problem that I linked it shows that if the person were search for global variables problems (more theorical) he'll find that is not a global variable problem.

Comment: @Makoto that's what Rubén is saying - OP is looking for theory, then they found the linked question which does not match their target, since it's not about theory.

Comment: Oh, okay, now I'm following @VLAZ.  This question might do with a bit of an edit to clarify that point then...

Comment: Re *"...or a random problem"*: Do you mean *"...of a random problem"* (typo)?

Comment: Peter Mortensen. Deleted. Not quite accurate. Still struggling to define it but the main idea is a more generic problem vs a very specific one that could involve typos or even the person that makes the question doesn't know exactly where is the problem ( for instance he thought that was a global variable problem and it wasn't).

Comment: But I was looking for problems related to JS global variables assignment ( I've already read the MDN docs and I have a problem implementing it). That title made me read the whole example to realize that wasn't what I was looking for. Maybe I'm asking for a better editing system and I wanted to read opinions about it. It lets me know if I'm misleading the point of Stackoverflow.

Comment: @Makoto, brother in SO, no I haven't read the linked question. At the moment of the comment I hadn't time to jump forth and back / wouldn't be able to do anything with that I could learned from that. It see that there are several comments since then and that the question was edited... At this moment I haven't time to read them, only I made time for you :) (and another notification that is waiting in the inbox)

Comment: Euh, Title sounds a bit like an April Fools Joke about "clearer" + "(more) generic" + "specific", => maybe an "Idea" to first make it specifically or generically clearer, and without any specific or generic Grammar Mistake(s)... :idea: // Quote: "*Should we make it clearer when someone is asking a more generic question over an specific implementation question?*" // OK, finally (hopefully) understood the Meaning after reading it 10 times, but I'm pretty sure it could be made specifically/generically clearer... :idea:

Comment: Ironically, I'm having trouble understanding the concrete problem here: specifically what search terms did you try? Specifically what did you hope to find? Specifically why were the results you found not applicable?

Answer (score 2):

Regarding what you shared about using the word "theory", please don't make quick conclusions for what you see on a screen. Stack Overflow, and life in general, will surprise you.

Regarding [What is the difference between "let" and "var"?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/762011/1595451), I don't like to classify it as a *theory* question, but it isn't strictly a practical question either. I think that it's better to say that a question is about the *general use* or about a *specific use*. I.E. JavaScript has a specification and many implementations. In a question about the general use of JavaScript it doesn't matter the engine to execute it, but on a specific use it might be required to specify what engine is used.

---

From the question

> Should we make it clearer when someone is asking a more generic question over an specific implementation question?

Yes, "always" that you found a question with a title that doesn't properly summarize the question body you "should" make an edit suggestion to change the question title to something that make it clearer the question subject.

Please bear in mind that you aren't forced to make an edit suggestion on questions and answers, or to do any other type of participation. If you are new to the question topic,  are unfamiliar with the question tags and with the Stack Overflow workings, please start by making suggestion edits and other type of participation in a slow pace.

While there are daily quotas for certain actions, I think that it's better to not deplete them as a "newbie".

Do a couple of edits suggestions and wait for their approval (or rejection) and feedback from the reviewers and other Stack Overflow users.

Spend time reading the tag wikis and [faqs](/questions/tagged/faqs) related to the activity that you want to do. Learn the vocabulary / argot used by the community to discuss the workings and to talk about the specific programming subject. When participating in Stack Overflow and other places, words should not be interpreted isolated of the context.